# Could anyone explain the below code snippet?

Tags: c++, c

```
void dec_exp(Decimal *result, const Decimal *a, unsigned int b)
    {
        Decimal tmp, power = *a;
        dec_parse(result, "1");
        while (b)
        {
            if (b & 1)
            {
                tmp = *result;
                dec_mul(result, &tmp, &power);
            }
            if (b >>= 1)
            {
                tmp = power;
                dec_mul(&power, &tmp, &tmp);
            }
    }
}
```

Where `Decimal` is a structure variable containing a decimal value, it's length and the position where the decimal point exists.

Passed arguments in the function: `a` is the base value and `b` is power. And `result` will store the value a^b after computation.

`dec_parse(Decimal &x,string y)` will do a parsing of `y` into decimal and extract info like the postion of decimal point, trim leading and trailing zeros and converts string into a `Decimal` structure variable.

`dec_mul(Decimal result, Decimal &x, Decimal &y)` will multiply `x` and `y` and store the value after multiplication in result.

I just want to know how two "if conditions" work in the while loop and when does the while loop get terminated and the time complexity of the snippet.

Comment: Do you understand the right-shift-assign (`>>=`) operator?

Comment: This is exponentiation by squaring.  The algorithm here is an implementation of the iterative algorithm shown on the wikipedia page.  It's pretty hard to know exactly what the time complexity will be, as this will be influenced by the time complexity of the `Decimal` operations, however the `while` loop will iterate at most the number of bits in `b`.  Wikipedia page has more information on complexity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Beta, I understand the >>= operator.

Comment: Thank you msandiford. Reading wiki page helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's computing `(*a)`<sup>`b`</sup> in the special case that `b` is a non-negative integer.

The variable `result` is initialized to one (note that `a`<sup>0</sup> is one for all `a`) and `power` is initialized to the contents of `a`. Each time through the loop, `result` is multiplied by `power` if `b` is odd (the first `if`). The second `if` right shifts `b` by one bit (i.e., divides by two), and if this is still positive, it squares `power`. In other words, `power` contains progressively larger values of `(*a)`<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>.

This is a fairly efficient and easily implementable (but not optimal) algorithm for computing a<sup>b</sup>. The optimal algorithm is NP-hard and (potentially) requires a lot of memory. This algorithm is easily encoded and requires minimal memory.

Ignoring the superfluous multiplication by one, this algorithm is optimal for `b`=0 to `b`=14. It is suboptimal in `a`<sup>15</sup>. This algorithm computes as `a`<sup>15</sup> `a`*`a`<sup>2</sup>*`a`<sup>4</sup>*`a`<sup>8</sup>, or six multiplications. The optimal calculation (the one with the least number of calls to `decimal`) is `a`<sup>3</sup>=`a`*`a`*`a`; `a`<sup>15</sup>=`a`<sup>3</sup>*((`a`<sup>3</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, or five multiplications.

---

Another name for this algorithm is right-to-left binary exponentiation. It's called that because it begins with the rightmost bit (the ones bit) of `b` and works on progressively more significant bits of `b`. In other words, it works right to left. Left-to-right binary exponentiation starts at the most significant bit of `b` and works on progressively less significant bits of `b`. After eliminating superfluous multiplications by one, both algorithms use exactly the same number of multiplications.

This is not the "optimal" algorithm, where optimal means "least number of multiplications". For example, the right-to-left and left-to-right binary exponentiation algorithms compute x<sup>15</sup> and x<sup>31</sup> as

- x<sup>15</sup> = x*x<sup>2</sup>*x<sup>4</sup>*x<sup>8</sup> = ((x<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>2</sup>*x (right-to-left and left-to-right, respectively)
- x<sup>31</sup> = x*x<sup>2</sup>*x<sup>4</sup>*x<sup>8</sup>*x<sup>16</sup> = (((x<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>2</sup>*x

But since 15=(4+1)*3, 31=15*2+1=((4+1)*3)*2+1 and 31=7*4+3=(3*2+1)*4+3 we can also write:

- x<sup>15</sup> = (x<sup>4</sup>*x)<sup>3</sup>
- x<sup>31</sup> = ((x<sup>4</sup>*x)<sup>3</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*x
- x<sup>31</sup> = (((x<sup>3</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*x)<sup>4</sup>)*x<sup>3</sup>

All require one less multiplication than does binary exponentiation. (The final expressions requires caching the intermediate result x<sup>3</sup> so as to avoid computing it twice.) I don't know if my expressions for x<sup>31</sup> are optimal. It's ridiculously hard to find the optimal expression even for smallish numbers. You have to look at all the different ways in which x<sup>n</sup> can be expressed, keeping in mind that common intermediate results only need to be calculated once. As mentioned above, this is NP-hard. In practice, binary exponentiation, although not optimal, is good enough.

Comment: Thanks David. I got the logic of exponentiation by squaring. Do we have any efficient logics apart from this? And I guess binary exponentiation is efficient than this.

Comment: @SPradhan - This **is** binary exponentiation. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`b & 1` tests if b is odd. If it is, `result` is set to `tmp * power`.

`b >>= 1` divides b by 2. If the result is non-zero, `tmp` is set to `power`, and `power` is set to `tmp * tmp`.

Eventually, `b` is divided by 2 so much that it reaches zero, which ends the `while` loop.

The algorithm is a generalization of so-called "[Russian Peasant multiplication](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html)" called "[Exponentiation by squaring](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Exponentiation_by_squaring)". The same basic process can be used for exponentiation instead of multiplication, by squaring the intermediate result (which we see in the second `if` test) rather than doubling.

Time complexity proportional to the highest set bit in `b`; if the highest set bit in `b` is bit *K* then the loop will iterate *K* times. That is, time complexity is proportional to the base 2 logarithm of b.

Comment: Thanks DrPizza. It helped a lot.